# Override translation of 1 word

Tags: plugins, translation

A few words in the WP Job Manager weren't translated yet. I edited most of them in de po file now but for the sentence "posted 5 hours ago" I can't find where to translate the "Hours"

It's declared as `%s` in the po file, Cant find the word hour in any of the plugin's files...

so where to change the "hours" term of this plugin.

```
#: templates/content-job_listing.php (Line 18)
msgid "%s ago"
msgstr "%s geleden"

// Content-job_listing.php
<li class="date">
    <date>
        <?php printf( 
            __( '%s ago', 'wp-job-manager' ), 
            human_time_diff( get_post_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) )
        ); ?>
    </date>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please post here the line exactly as it looks in the file where you've found it ?

Comment: See edit. And in content-job_listing.php (editor does not show it above)
<li class="date"><date><?php printf( __( '%s ago', 'wp-job-manager' ),          human_time_diff( get_post_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></date></li>

Comment: You shouldn't need to translate it as `human_time_diff()` in WordPress core handles it's own translations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your problem resolves around the fact that the WP theme developers used a function that doesn't have any hooks so we could easily alter the output, you're going to have to copy & paste the following code in your functions.php file

```
function human_time_diff( $from, $to = '' ) {
    if ( empty( $to ) ) {
        $to = time();
    }

    $diff = (int) abs( $to - $from );

    if ( $diff < HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $mins = round( $diff / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $mins <= 1 )
            $mins = 1;
        /* translators: min=minute */
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s min', '%s mins', $mins ), $mins );
    } elseif ( $diff < DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $hours = round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $hours <= 1 )
            $hours = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s hour', '%s hours', $hours ), $hours );
    } elseif ( $diff < WEEK_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $days = round( $diff / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $days <= 1 )
            $days = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s day', '%s days', $days ), $days );
    } elseif ( $diff < 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $weeks = round( $diff / WEEK_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $weeks <= 1 )
            $weeks = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s week', '%s weeks', $weeks ), $weeks );
    } elseif ( $diff < YEAR_IN_SECONDS && $diff >= 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $months = round( $diff / ( 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ) );
        if ( $months <= 1 )
            $months = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s month', '%s months', $months ), $months );
    } elseif ( $diff >= YEAR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $years = round( $diff / YEAR_IN_SECONDS );
        if ( $years <= 1 )
            $years = 1;
        $since = sprintf( _n( '%s year', '%s years', $years ), $years );
    }

    /**
     * Filter the human readable difference between two timestamps.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $since The difference in human readable text.
     * @param int    $diff  The difference in seconds.
     * @param int    $from  Unix timestamp from which the difference begins.
     * @param int    $to    Unix timestamp to end the time difference.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'human_time_diff', $since, $diff, $from, $to );
}
```

> '%s min', '%s mins'
>
> '%s hour', '%s hours'
>
> '%s day', '%s days'
>
> '%s week', '%s weeks'
>
> '%s month', '%s months'

These are the formats you need to change with your own wording; be sure to only change the words (minute, hour, day, week, month) and not the `%s`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunately the website crashed when adding that to functions.php.

Will go and try on my localhost first now to resolve it

Comment: Your site crash because you are trying to define the same function two times. The recomendation of the answer of copy and paste the code in theme functions.php is far away to be a solution (I'm sorry to say that).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to understand how the code you are using works. The code that output the string is:

```
<?php printf( __( '%s ago', 'wp-job-manager' ), human_time_diff( get_post_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?>
```

In the above code, `__( '%s ago', 'wp-job-manager' )` is translated by wp-job-manager language files and `%s` is replaced by the output of `human_time_diff()` function, which is in the format "1 day", "2 months", etc. The output of `human_time_diff()` is already translated by WordPress language files and, additionally, the output can be filtered. So, you have two options: 1) modify the output of `human_time_diff()` function using `human_time_diff` filter or 2)  override the translations from core ussing `gettext` filter.

1.- **Using `human_time_diff` filter**. Example:

```
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', function($since, $diff, $from, $to) {

    //Here you can build your own human time diff strings
   //For example
   if ( empty( $to ) ) {
        $to = time();
    }

    $diff = (int) abs( $to - $from );

    if ( $diff < HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
        $since = "WOW, a lot of time ago!!!!";
    }

   return $since;

}, 10, 4 );
```

2.- **Override the translations** using `gettext` filter. For example:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function($translated, $original, $domain) {

    if ( $original == "%s hour" ) {
        //fill $translated string with whatever you want
        $translated = "Some other string you want instead of original translattion";
    }
    return $translated;

}, 10, 3 );
```